# I need a C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

If possible I want one that's free, popular (so support on forums will be faster) and.... just good. I don't really know much about compilers so I don't know what exactly is good.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please note that I have taken the below stuff from **Link :**http://cplus.about.com/od/glossary/a/compilers.htm

I have coped relevant things here for more detail you can visit link directly

> - Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express.
> - Linkfrm.
> - Turbo Explorer for C++.
> - GCC (GNU Compiler Collection)
> - Digital Mars C/C++ Compiler

Comment: Embarcadero killed the Turbo Explorer for C++. There is no more, they have only links to the trial version of C++ Builder. Such a shame.

Comment: It's not clear that you're copy-pasting an article. You should acknowledge your source more clearly.

Comment: Given that the question didn't specify OS, I'd like to see some indication of which are Windows-only and which aren't for all compilers, not just three.  Also, some of the wording doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, I will learn from experience

Answer (score 17):

I guess you want the GNU C++ Compiler from the [GNU Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Answer (score 6):

You don't mention what platform you're using, but the [Microsoft Visual C++ Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/VC/) is free and popular.

Comment: That's implied by being from Microsoft. :)

Comment: I hear it works well in WINE...

Comment: So? GCC (4.4 at least) is still superior

Answer (score 4):

Try the [GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) C++ compiler](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

Comment: Just wanted to clarify for peeps who may not know, that GCC == GNU Compiler Collection - ie they are one and the same.

Answer (score 3):

Try one of these:

- http://www.openwatcom.org (including a a IDE)
- http://llvm.org/ with it's Gnu based compilers
- And of course: The Gnu C/C++ Tool Chain (as mentioned by someone earlier)

All the above are open sourced.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the GNU Complier Collection, it includes C++, C, Objective-C, Java and a bunch of others. Its free, its open source, its highly popular, you can get it for almost any platform, and its commonly used as a base for popular IDE's.

gcc.gnu.org

Answer (score 2):

Dev C++ bloodshed from boorland, is easier to use than Microsoft Visual C++ and it shouldn't take more than 5 minutes to understand the user-interface. 
 [Dev-C++ 5.0 beta 9.2 (4.9.9.2) (9.0 MB) with Mingw/GCC 3.4.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/files/Binaries/Dev-C%2B%2B%204.9.9.2/devcpp-4.9.9.2_setup.exe/download)

Answer (score 2):

The Intel C++ compiler is available for free on Linux for non-commercial use. Generates highly optimized code and can even auto-vectorize/parallelize suitable code.

Based on my experience, it generates considerably faster code than GCC (4.3) and MS VC++ 2008

Comment: "free for non-commercial use" sounds fishy to me - how does that work?  Can they enforce license conditions based on whether you sell the resulting software?  If so looks like it would not be possible to use either for open source (well GPL at least which doesn't allow such restrictions) or for commercial software either - only for freeware.

Comment: @thomasrutter - you are probably right. however, you could write a package (something like fftw) that you distribute as GPL, but provide comparative benchmarks when built with icc. whoever uses it has the option to use icc to build it if they wish.

FWIU, GPL only applies to the source, not the compiler used to build the source. i guess you could have your source distributed as GPL and provide a prebuild binary for anyone who wants to use it for non-commercial purposes. would this work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to use [Microsoft Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/Default.aspx). It works very well, creates fast code and it is widely discussed on forums. Then you can go further with Microsoft Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I like the dev c++ because you can compile a single c++ file without first needing to make a whole new project and include it.
fairly easy to use imo

Comment: True also of the GCC (GNU compiler collection) and its Windows port MinGW.  But you can also use pretty powerful build systems with it once your project gets large so it scales well.

Comment: Oops just realised that Dev C++ **is** based on MinGW. I'll shut up now!

Answer (score 0):

i use c-free 5.it is based on mingw5,and it's free.moreover,it has simpler user interface than code::blocks,and definitely much more simpler than microsoft vc++.moreover,you may,or may not create projects,files,compile tham directly,or don't compile them at all.i would suggest c-free.